# Get css selector from a Site Prism page object

Tags: ruby, capybara, site-prism

Is there a way to get the css selector for a page object you defined in SitePrism? For instance if I have

```
class myPageObject < SitePrism::Page
  ...
  element :my_element, '.my-element-class'
  ...
end
```

How could I use the selector in a test to get `.my-element-class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - SitePrism doesn't store the parameters passed to `element` in any accessible way

Comment: Aright thanks for helping, figured I'd ask as I couldn't find any information on it while I was looking.

Answer (score 0):

*Old post but adding for info*

A specific element on a page will only have 1 xpath (Or possible a subset of these), but it is very definitely *finite*. This is because of the way xpath is inherently structured. It represents the DOM.

CSS Selectors can be defined in a multitude of ways, and as such it can be considered than a single element could have *infinite* css selectors.

If you want to find out the specific **class** property of an element, that is possible by doing `my_page.my_element['class']` - However this will return a space delimited string of just the class properties of the current element.